# Is $ k_1a + k_2b + k_3c = 0$ for arbitrary but fixed numbers $ k_1, k_2, k_3 \in \mathbb{R} $ a subspace in $\mathbb{R^3}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, invariant-subspace

Need some guidance at this task:

I have $k_1a + k_2b + k_3c = 0$ for arbitrary but fixed numbers $k_1, k_2, k_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ and need to show if (let's call it $V$) is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$.

$i)\ V \neq \emptyset \\
ii)\ \forall a,b,c \in V : a+b \in V \\
iii)\ \forall a \in V : \forall k \in K : k  \cdot a \in V 
 $

Okay, usually I know how to show the subspace properly, but I am confused a little bit by the $k_1, k_2, k_3$ variables.

Could anyone help me out how to show it properly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question does not make a whole lot of sense. What does "random but fixed" mean? What are $a,b,c$? Can you state a set theoretically precise definition of $V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k_1,k_2,k_3\in\mathbb{R}$ be fixed, and let

$$V=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : k_1x+k_2y+k_3z=0\}.$$

We show that $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Now as

$$k_1\cdot 0+k_2\cdot 0+k_3\cdot 0=0$$

we have that $(0,0,0)\in V$. Now let $(x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2)\in\mathbb{R}^3$. Then, as

$$k_1(x_1+x_2)+k_2(y_1+y_2)+k_3(z_1+z_2)=(k_1x_1+k_2y_1+k_3z_3)+(k_1x_2+k_2y_2+k_3z_3)=0+0=0,$$

it follows that $(x_1,y_1,z_1)+(x_2,y_2,z_2)\in V$. Finally, let $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and $(x,y,z)\in V$. Then, as

$$k_1(\lambda x)+k_2(\lambda y)+k_3(\lambda z)=\lambda(k_1x+k_2y+k_3z)=\lambda\cdot 0=0,$$

it follows that $\lambda (x,y,z)\in V$. Thus $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Very nice, exactly what i was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! If you're curious, this actually generalize further, and is just a special case of what is know as the orthogonal complement of an inner product space, which you can prove always is a subspace in a similar manner. So here we would have that $V=\operatorname{span}\{(k_1,k_2,k_3)\}^\perp$, for example.

Comment: wow! didn't know and i will definitely look further into it!